# Redeploy of Azure Deployment slot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

If I redeploy an already deployed staging slot through ARM with updated appsettings where the appsettings is set through properties.siteconfig.appsettings, will it update the appsettings properly? Or do I have to delete the staging slot first?

Reason I ask is because an empty siteconfig is used to not copy production slot settings when deployment slot is first created. So it seems like slots is somewhat carved in stone.

I am currently looking into all deployment slots for a customer and I am not able to try this myself. Therefore this question.

Comment: All settings defined in the portal override the values that may be present in the (app settings) web.config file. You can also define specific-slot settings. Defining application settings on a Deployment Slot works the same as defining them on the application it self, and that is by adding a resource of the name “appsettings” to the resources array of the Deployment Slot.

Comment: @AjayKumar-MSFT but if I add them through siteconfig I can see that it overrides config changes when I have done a swap. I really don't understand any of this deployment slot stuff when doing ARM templates. It is so confusing.